# running python files in powershell

Tags: python, powershell

For a project at school I need to run a python file using powershell. I tried installing the interpreter and using the command `python pythonTest.py` but nothing happened.

Do i need to import something in powershell?

Comment: nothing happened? like what? can you paste the text of the powershell console?

Comment: Close and reopen the terminal, then retry. If that still doesn't work, and assuming you installed python correctly, python.exe is not on your PATH environment variable, so you need to fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED
I was running it in admin mode and apparently it doesn't work when you're in adminmode

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the box add python to path when you install python. So first uninstall then reinstall making sure you ticked the checkbox and proceed then you can run python files in powershell.

Comment: Or, you know, add it to PATH manually instead of uninstalling and reinstalling everything... it's not that hard